# IndexError: list index out of range using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to learn how to web scrape and I decided to try scraping off of Stats Royale, a mobile game that I play. I followed some easy steps with automating the boring stuff but I wanted to challenge my self with some harder code. However, after I run the code, it states that there is an index error at "return trophy[0].text.strip()".

```
from selenium import webdriver
import bs4

def Trophycount():
    print('What is the player\'s tag number?')
    tag = input()
    elems.send_keys(tag)
    elems.submit()
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup('html.parser')
    trophy = soup.select('#profile-metrics > div > 
    div.statistic__metricGroupMain > div:nth-child(2) > 
    div.statistics__metricCounter.ui__headerExtraSmall')
    print('The player\'s highest trophy count is:')
    return trophy[0].text.strip()

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
html = browser.get('https://statsroyale.com')
elems = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#search-bar > input')
elems.click()
Trophycount()
```

Comment: Then clearly there is nothing at `trophy[0]`, which means your `soup.select` didn't find what you asked it to find.

Comment: Try selecting by class, using: `statistics__metricCounter`. You are being too specific with your current selection.